# django admin save model

Tags: django, django-admin

Есть иерархические категории и нужно составлять url, по slug

Сейчас хочу хранить это в базе, чтобы каждый раз не бегать по родителям

```
def get_slug_list_for_categories(self):
    try:
        ancestors = self.get_ancestors(include_self=True)
    except:
        ancestors = []
    else:
        ancestors1 = [i.slug for i in ancestors]

    slugs = []

    for i in range(len(ancestors)):
        slugs.append('/'.join(ancestors1[:i+1]))

    return (slugs, self.name)
```

Проблема в том что не могу понять как это сделать, нашел методы это

`def __init__` или `def save`. `save` метод делает бесконечную рекурсию, def `__init__`, каждый раз инициализируется и делает то же самое то что и я.

И я не могу создавать, его перед сохранением,то есть не могу вытащить родителей если не была создана model и еще одно условие, если бы категории добавлялись по порядку, тогда можно было ориентироваться по id.

И нужно добавлять это в админке

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно добавить вызов функции после вызова save, используя сигнал [post_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/signals/#post-save) или любой другой более подходящий сигнал.